# How to keep one column unsorted in DataTable when using DefaultView.Sort

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sorting, datatable

I have some DataTable tbl1:

```
 RowNumber   Column1
 ---------  --------
    1          xyz
    2          foo
    3          bar
```

I use `tbl1.DefaultView.Sort = "Column1 asc";`, set tbl1 as DataSource to GridView and the result is:

```
 RowNumber   Column1
 ---------  --------
    3          bar
    2          foo
    1          xyz
```

What I need is the values in RowNumber column to stay how they was but Column1 need to be sorted. Like this:

```
RowNumber    Column1
 ---------  --------
    1          bar
    2          foo
    3          xyz
```

One more thing - I need it to be done in tbl1 itself or in GridView but not in clientside (JavaScript) and not with embeded code block in page.
Any good solution for this or I need to iterate every table row and set RowNumber manually every time I use column sorting?
Thank you.

Comment: How are you generating the rownumber in the first place? I dont think this can be done without regenerating the rownumbers and it would probably be better to do it on the db if you are using one

Comment: I am getting all data except RowNumber column from database, then add column RowNumber to tbl1 and values in it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

Code In Front

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gv_Sorting">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="rowNumber">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("RowNo") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="foo" SortExpression="Foo">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Foo") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
private string _sortDirection = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Varaible
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String[] array = { "xyz", "foo", "bar" };
        dt.Columns.Add("Foo");
        dt.Column.Add("RowNo");

        // Loop
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(array[i], (i + 1).ToString());

        // Check & Bind
        if (dt != null)
        {
            // ViewState
            ViewState["Data"] = dt;

            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.DataBind();

            // Dispose
            dt.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

protected void gv_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    _sortDirection = ViewState["SortFoo"] != null ? ViewState["SortFoo"] + "" : "";

    SetSortDirection(_sortDirection);

    ViewState["SortFoo"] = _sortDirection;

    DataTable dt = ViewState["Data"] as DataTable;
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + _sortDirection;

    // Define New DataTable
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Column.Add("Foo");
    dt1.Column.Add("RowNo");

    // Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
         dt1.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Foo"] + "", (i + 1).ToString()); 

    // Save to ViewState
    ViewState["SortFoo"] = dt1;        

    // Bind
    gv.DataSource = dt1;
    gv.DataBind();

}

private void SetSortDirection(string sortDirection)
{

    if (sortDirection == "") _sortDirection = "ASC";
    else if (sortDirection == "ASC") _sortDirection = "DESC";
    else _sortDirection = "ASC";
}
```

Comment: Thank you BUT you did it with an embeded code (<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>). As I mentioned before I need it to be done in tbl1 itself or in GridView because I need this row numbers in serverside too.

Comment: Updated the code but I didn't test it. I just mock up the code as above.... You required to reconstruct the DataTable due to the number arrangement change.